# Knockout dynamic templates do not load in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-9

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bL7qatx1/

In IE10+\Chrome\FF, the above fiddle works fine. However, in IE9 the template dynamically added does not load into the div (the script is loaded into the DOM).

```
var contentsElem = $('#contents');

var dynamicTemplateContents = '<div>This is the dynamic template...</div>';
var scriptElem = $('<script id="dynamic-template" type="text/html">');
scriptElem.html(dynamicTemplateContents);
$('body').append(scriptElem);

var vm = {
    template1: 'static-template',
    template2: 'dynamic-template',
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I found https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/777, which implies that it should work. However, it seems like there's something different about my code.

The script element is added to the DOM, but isn't bound to the div in KO. Is this not supported in IE9 for some reason? Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what was different with my code...

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bL7qatx1/1/

Aparently...

```
var scriptElem = $('<script id="dynamic-template" type="text/html">');
scriptElem.html(dynamicTemplateContents);
$('body').append(scriptElem);
```

... is not the same as...

```
$('body').append('<script type="text/html" id="dynamic-template">'+dynamicTemplateContents+'</' + 'script>');
```

... on IE9. Not sure why, though. (If anyone knows, I'd be interested to hear an explanation)

Comment: It looks like it's a quirk of the DOM in IE9.  If you start inspecting the elements, the initial version appears to have embedded an entire div element etc within the script tag, with indentation/newlines etc as you'd expect.  The second one is all inline with the script opening and closing tags all on one line.  Based on this, I tried using `.text` rather than `.html` - that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/6ubm17ta/1/